# In Rails, how to call same methods on every concern and in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, super, activesupport-concern

I have a model and quite a few concerns, I want to call the same method from every concern and from the model itself, and I was wondering if this is possible.

So let’s say I have a model like this, it has three concerns and a setup_defaults method.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    include ConcernOne
    include ConcernTwo
    include ConcernThree

    def setup_defaults
        # model code here
    end
end
```

I want to have a `setup_defaults` in each concern that runs as well as in the one in the model so it looks like this:

```
module ConcernOne
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    def setup_defaults
        # concern one code
    end
end

module ConcernTwo
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    def setup_defaults
        # concern two code
    end
end

module ConcernThree
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    def setup_defaults
        # concern three code
    end
end
```

So I want `concern one code`, then `concern two code` then `concern one code` and then finally `model code here` to run in that order.

I’ve tried using super like this but it only runs the last concern code and then the model code:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    include ConcernOne
    include ConcernTwo
    include ConcernThree

    def setup_defaults
        super
        # model code here
    end
end
```

Can I run all 3 concerns `setup_defaults` and then the model’s `setup_defaults`?  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I run all 3 concerns `setup_defaults` and then the model’s `setup_defaults`? Is this possible?

Yes, and you already have it. The only bit you're missing is invoking your concerns from each other.

```
module ConcernOne
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def setup_defaults
    super if defined?(super) # do the same for other concerns and the model
    puts 'one'
  end
end
```

Output:

```
Item.new.setup_defaults
# >> one
# >> two
# >> three
# >> main
```